# Installing git on ubuntu 14.04 crashed

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, git

I'm unable to install git on ubuntu here is the response

```
sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also I've tried installing liberror-perl which I couldn't

```
sudo apt-get install liberror-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package liberror-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'liberror-perl' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did you use some ppa? Git installs without any problems.

Comment: And `liberror-perl` is installable.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: using  `sudo apt-get install -f` gave this

Comment: using  `sudo apt-get install -f` gave some packages to remove so I had to run this command `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: It looks like you are not using Ubuntu 14.04. Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What's the output to `lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release`?

Comment: `trusty
4.2.0-35-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow mentioned below steps:

**Step-1:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step-2:**

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

**Step-3:**

```
Sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**Step-4:**

```
Sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Don't you mean `clean` and not `autoclean`?

Comment: autoclean remove backup files which are download under installation session.